# Please revert to hiding things I've flagged

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, 10k-tools

I don't want to see the posts I've already flagged in the queue, please can it be reverted to how it was?

[image]

Comment: Since there are no actions that can be taken against these greyed-out-unless-you-hover entries, why are they even being shown? Who thought that was a good idea? :o

Comment: @Flyk Especially as I can see my flag history anyway if I want to see what I've flagged.

Comment: Well I recently got 10k on Drupal Answers and [it was confusing to see that there are items in a queue, but do not see any items there](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/2756/16495). Maybe you got used to the way it was, but the way it is now is more consistent.

Comment: I don't have access to the tool, but I suppose that the gray out effect is handled by a css class. Wouldn't a checkbox/filter that hides all element with that class be enough? Anyway, if it really brother you and they don't change it.... I would consider to use greasemonkey and implement the filter yourself

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Although it would have taken slightly less time to add a line to my SE userscript to that effect than to post this question, *that's not the point*.

Comment: @fredley - I know that, but I also suggested a workaround in case they don't fix that. Didn't you notice my support vote :P?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about a compromise?

I've made it so any post you've flagged will be hidden by default, but a **"show posts you've already flagged"** link will appear at the bottom of the list.  Clicking it will show the already-flagged posts with the grayed-out styling.

This hopefully will allay the concerns of people that visit the page and see nothing, even when the count is in the header*.

<sub>* how to handle that count [is being discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212375/remove-the-flag-notification-in-the-top-bar-when-i-have-done-my-job-with-it#comment684063_212375)</sub>