# Why does the top bar notify me about flagged posts when I have no flags left?

Tags: discussion, notifications, 10k-tools, top-bar

Even when I have no remaining flags, the top bar still shows me (and updates) the flagged posts counter (highlighted in blue).

[image: Screenshot from Stack Oveflow]

Is there a special reason for this?
AFAIK I can do *nothing* at `/tools/flagged` when I have no flags left, so there is no need to catch my attention (which this blue background color does).

If I don’t miss something, I think it might be a good idea to hide this notifier unless I have at least one flag available again. Resp. replace it with a un-highlighted "tools" link.

Comment: Possibly related or possibly duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212375/remove-the-flag-notification-in-the-top-bar-when-i-have-done-my-job-with-it

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Not a duplicate. That one's about flags that you've already piled on or counterflagged; this one's about not having the ability to handle new flags.

Comment: You also get it even though you've acted on all the flags (which you'll see if you click through).  My guess would be that the value is computed site-wide, not for each user, and that the extra server round-trips and computation was deemed to be too expensive for the benefit gained.  (The same thing happens with pending edits if the pending ones are yours -- you can't approve them but you still get the notice.)

Comment: @michaelb958 yup, I also realized it's not a duplicate as soon as a quick edit was added to this question that added the image. It's still a bit related though.