# The number of posts to review stopped making any sense since I hit 10k rep

Tags: bug, review

Though correlation doesn't imply causation I think there's a link between me hitting 10k rep and seeing this review count in the top bar:

[image: image description]

It makes no sense at all and is **always** more than 200. This even happens when I reviewed 20 of almost each queue and certainly had nothing to review. The count doesn't add up even if I subtract 200 from the number.

What does the number exactly mean? If it's broken I'm gonna ad-block it because it harms my attention for no reason.

[Here's an example screenshot of actual numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4kUI.png)

Comment: Related feature request: [Please dim the color of the review task counter when there are no actionable tasks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231051/300411)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed a [10k privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).  As explained [when it was implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726/300411), the number is meant to be *informational*, fitting in with the other 10k privileges.  It shows everything currently pending on the site, including things that you can't personally act upon, such as:

- Things you've already done (e.g., low-quality answers you've already handled but whose status hasn't been finalized yet)
- Things you've skipped
- Things you are responsible for (like suggested tag wiki edits, answers you've flagged, etc.)

The idea is to give you a high-level overview of the site status, not an indicator of how many things you can personally do.

<sup>Not that I'm a fan: I'm a recent 10k user on my home site and I have upvoted the above linked feature request!</sup>

Comment: Ah ok then, ad-blocking. That feature does not provide helpful information in any way.