# What does the tilde character mean?

Tags: support, review

[image]

What does the tilde character in the above screenshot mean? Does it represent "*approximately 900 posts are awaiting for review*"?

Answer (score 7):

Yup, the tilde (~) means approximately.
I assume it's rounded to the nearest hundreds.

Comment: Not rounded, as much as there due to caching and the fact that if one has reviewed a post it will not be queued for them.

Answer (score 7):

The number is not actually how many review tasks there are for *you*. I'm guessing this is for the same reasons as explained for the old flag counts [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212375/203101) (read the comments).

Basically, the number you see in the top bar does not change for different users. So, if you have already reviewed one of these, the number does not reflect that. As a result, the number shown is an approximation and you are likely not to find the same number of tasks waiting in the review queues as you see in the top bar.