# Why do I see already reviewed items in the flag queue

Tags: support, flags, 10k-tools, flag-queue

Today I reviewed a lot of flags and noticed that items I already reviewed still appear in the flag queue which was getting annoying the more items I reviewed.

According to [this not so old post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212335/please-revert-to-hiding-things-ive-flagged) there should be a switch at the bottom of the page making it possible to hide such items. But there is none.

Is this a bug or has this feature been removed on purpose and if so why?