# Close vote review queue shows me question I've already voted on

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-close

I was going through some close votes through the review queue, when it showed me this:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4288297

Which I had already voted to close on Feb 19, and so am no longer allowed to vote to close this again.

Why did it show up? Anyways, it looks like a bug.

I do see some duplicates, but they are all apparently bug reports which were fixed a long time ago, and this happened today, so not sure if I vote to reopen those old duplicates, or post as new bug, guessing the second.

Comment: Same issue here: [why-do-i-see-already-reviewed-items-in-the-flag-queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224646/)

Comment: Different issue, @juergend - this is regarding /review, yours is regarding /tools/flagged

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is supposed to be prevented - there's logic to make sure you haven't voted to close a given question before showing it to you in the close queue.

...However, it doesn't verify that you haven't *flagged* it for closure. Which in this case, you did.

It's pretty rare that someone gets the chance to both flag and vote for closure, but the logic could probably be expanded to check for both.

Comment: I just recently went over 3k (since feb 19), is that the only way this can happen?

Comment: It's the most likely scenario, yeah. Still rare, but we've had a few reports of this in the past.

Comment: @Shog9 I got one of these about a month ago as an audit - I failed and wanted to see which stupid user closed it - and I was one of them - not just a flag

Comment: That... sounds like something else, @Mark.

Comment: So is this [meta-tag:status-we-will-fix-it-if-someone-wants-to]?

Comment: Pretty much. It's a really, *really* easy fix if someone happens to be in the code already; probably not worth opening otherwise.

Comment: The next build will include the fix @Shog9 so eloquently pointed out.  It will verify that you haven't flagged it for closure before giving you a task.